# SwiftUI how can I create unique sublists from user input

Tags: swift, list, navigation

I’m trying to get my head around creating a simple sublist from user text field input.

So if the user wants a sublist B inside sublist A, then sublist C inside sublist B and so on, endlessly.

The way I’m trying to tackle the problem I’m having is; a list needs its own user created navlink to create a sublist but how can I repeat these sublists (let’s say from a text field) and have them able to repeat throughout endless sublists.

Essentially, I need a unique destination view to generate whenever a user creates a sublist, that view needs to hold its own list items and be able to generate further unique destination views etc.

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct Item: Identifiable {
     let id = UUID()
     let title: String
     let children: [Item]?
 }

struct ContentView: View {

@State var items: [Item] = [
        Item(title: "List", children: [
        Item(title: "subList A", children: nil)])
    ]

     var body: some View {
 VSTack {
        List(items, children: \.children) {
             Text($0.title)
        }
    }
     }
 }
```

So is it possible to append the items array that would create a  new subList, anywhere in the hierarchy depending on user input?

Comment: Do you have any code that you can share with your current approach?

Comment: Added some code, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that will suffice as an answer to your question, but essentially you can listen to user input through a published variable(basically any sort of input you like) and when you receive an input, you can recursively check for what ever conditions you want, for example,
checking if children is nil

```
func addChildrenToHiercy(withItems items: [Item], parent: [Items]) {
    if let children = parent.children {
        self.addChildrenToHiercy(withItems: items, parent: children)
    }  else {
        parent.children = items
    }
}
```

Now every time you call "addChildrenToHiercy" he will add you a sublist to the nil value children  in your hiarcy.